# Can't check permission correctly at API Level < 23

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I'm developing an Android library for Unity3D, and I have problems in checking Audio Permission.
At first I used **ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()**, but failed:
the problem was:

```
10-16 13:46:39.466 856-939/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
                                              at com.magikid.unityplugin.RecordManager.isGotRecordPermission(RecordManager.java:431)
                                              at com.magikid.unityplugin.RecordManager.RequestRecordPermission(RecordManager.java:370)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                              at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.magikid.channel-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.magikid.channel-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at dalvik."
```

After updating API, the using of android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat is confusing, and after adding android-support-v4.jar, the problem was fixed.I can either use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission or PermissionChecker.checkCallingOrSelfPermission or PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission, no other error exists, but its value always return PERMISSION_GRANTED.
Then I tried to use **PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission()** instead in [Cannot resolve method “checkSelfPermission”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172519/cannot-resolve-method-checkselfpermission) with adding android-support-v4.jar, it just seemed like that everything turns ok: I got the result of check which was PERMISSION_GRANTED, however after that when I tried to deny the permission, the check still returned PERMISSION_GRANTED.
By the way, I've distinguished different API lvl, here are my codes:

```
public class AppUtils 
{
  private static Application application;

  public static void setApplication(Application application) 
  {
    try 
    {
      if (AppUtils.application == null) 
      {
        AppUtils.application = application;
      } 
      else 
      {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Application already holded 'application'.");
      }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      Log.e("UnityDebugSetApp", String.valueOf(e));
    }
  }
}
public class RecordManager
{
  public static Context getContext() 
  {
    return application.getApplicationContext();
  }

  //This method is to judge if user allows permission
  public static boolean isGotRecordPermission()
  {
    Activity activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    String permissionName = "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO";
    String pkgName = activity.getPackageName();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= 23) 
    {
      return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == getAppContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission (permissionName);
    } 
    else 
    {
      return PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED == PermissionChecker.checkCallingOrSelfPermission (getAppContext(), permName);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    provided files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/wechat-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/flame.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

If my question is not clear or you need more details, please comment to let me know, I'll try my best to help you to help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Whats with the problem with ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()? What error are you getting?

Comment: Dear @AbhayBohra, I've updated the information for you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run Time permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) are introduced in Android 6.0(23). On a device below Android 6.0 it suffices to ask permissions inside AndroidManifest.xml file. It autmatically returns granted.If your targetSdk is 23 or above you need to ask Run Time permissions but if user's device is less than 23 asking permission in run time is ignored and you are granted the permission if it's asked inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Tanks for URL, I've read it carefully and I can't get solutions for lower API. And now I know the exact reason: Ignoring, thank you.

Comment: There is no solution for lower APIs because that feature is implemented in Android 6.0 because users complaining about security, accessing their files, etc. Privacy Policies and run time permissions are introduced to give users more control over their devices and to be aware of why permissions asked. There is no Run Time permission  for previous versions also means there is no solution or you are automatically granted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

as @Faith said Run time permission api is not available under api 23 ,permissions declared in manifest file is enough.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to check permission to make sure if user wants to use record function in run-time to call back :)

Answer (score 0):

All the permission in android are added in API 23 and below this API all the permissions are granted already via manifest.
so we need to check API version of user device running OS version in android device.
Android official document : [click here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
and i suggest to use 
this library its handy and easy to use.

```
https://github.com/NikhilJogdand/PermissionManager
```

All the callback and os version checking related task is performed by this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxPermissions to grant permissions in your app.It is very easy to use

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);

rxPermissions
    .request(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
    .subscribe(granted -> {
        if (granted) { 
            // Permission Granted
        } else {
           // Permission denied
        }
    });
```

For more information follow this link
https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I'm trying and get some problems in "subscribe": cant resolve method 'subscribe (<lambda expression>)', and the 2nd "granted" is Incompatible types: boolean is required not <lambda parameter>. How can I fix them?

Comment: Did you add gradle dependancy for rxPermissions library?

Comment: yep: <br>dependencies {compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.4@aar'<br>}<br>repositories {
    jcenter() // If not already there<br>}

Comment: Then I added compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
} in gradle, new error exists: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.reactivex.Observable, finally this Answer saved me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048520/rxandroid-and-retrofit-unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-io-reactivex-observabl

Comment: And need newest me.tatarka.retrolambda: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/me.tatarka.retrolambda